# Accumulating minimums of subsequent variables to one column

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyeval

With the data like attached I want to pull out the minimum of selected columns and accumulate them within `(Intercept)` column. The remaining variables should be a difference between original variable value and subtracted minimum. I have written a function that does that for one selected columns and tried to use `purrr:map_at` to call it on few selected columns. But the following code doesn't work - not only it doesn't pull out minimums, but also return a list of subsequent dates, while I obviously want to retain `data.frame` structure.

```
structure(list(`2016-01-01` = c(19.612765930918, 0.0139082609319898, 
0.298043103003794, -0.217012113254805), `2016-01-02` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.153780074988214, 0.317999312583603, -0.192164881529573), `2016-01-03` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.150571795109967, 0.515644453462975, -0.269251568581305), `2016-01-04` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.142512722884255, 0.261814150174792, -0.160625206980914), `2016-01-05` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.0778498178207942, 0.464855455837326, -0.15224027496774), `2016-01-06` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.0314062544574153, 0.278014325308919, -0.19657100740319)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("(Intercept)", 
"x1", "x2", "x3"))

min_to_base <- function(impacts, var) {
  var <- ensym(var)

  impacts %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    mutate(min = min(!!var),
           !!var := !!var - min,
           `(Intercept)` = `(Intercept)` + min) %>% 
    select(-min)
}

impacts %>% 
  map_at(c('x1', 'x2'), ~min_to_base(., .x))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to subtract the minimums of `x1` and `x2` from those columns, and add those minimums to `(Intercept)`? If so, this should work

```
library(tidyverse)

min_to_base <- function(df, cols){
  mins <- lapply(df[cols], min)
  df[cols] <- df[cols] - mins
  df['(Intercept)'] <- df['(Intercept)'] + do.call(sum, mins)
  df
}

impacts %>% 
  t %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = 'dt') %>% 
  min_to_base(c('x1', 'x2'))


#   dt         `(Intercept)`     x1     x2     x3
#   <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2016-01-01          19.9 0      0.0362 -0.217
# 2 2016-01-02          19.9 0.140  0.0562 -0.192
# 3 2016-01-03          19.9 0.137  0.254  -0.269
# 4 2016-01-04          19.9 0.129  0      -0.161
# 5 2016-01-05          19.9 0.0639 0.203  -0.152
# 6 2016-01-06          19.9 0.0175 0.0162 -0.197
```

Here's a kind of hacky way to make the function behave as NSE (same result as above).

```
min_to_base <- function(df, ...){
  cols <- as.character(ensyms(...))
  mins <- lapply(df[cols], min)
  df[cols] <- df[cols] - mins
  df['(Intercept)'] <- df['(Intercept)'] + do.call(sum, mins)
  df
}

impacts %>% 
  t %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = 'dt') %>% 
  min_to_base(x1, x2)
```

Data used:

```
impacts <- 
structure(list(`2016-01-01` = c(19.612765930918, 0.0139082609319898, 
0.298043103003794, -0.217012113254805), `2016-01-02` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.153780074988214, 0.317999312583603, -0.192164881529573), `2016-01-03` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.150571795109967, 0.515644453462975, -0.269251568581305), `2016-01-04` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.142512722884255, 0.261814150174792, -0.160625206980914), `2016-01-05` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.0778498178207942, 0.464855455837326, -0.15224027496774), `2016-01-06` = c(19.612765930918, 
0.0314062544574153, 0.278014325308919, -0.19657100740319)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("(Intercept)", 
"x1", "x2", "x3"))
```

Comment: Yes, but I also need to generalise it and make it work for any number of columns. Your approach will require inputting the column names twice - in 4 and 5 line. Do you have any idea how to make it less cumbersome?

Comment: See my edit for a solution requiring only one specification of the relevant columns.

Comment: Please use `as.character(ensyms(...))` instead of the `gsub` hack ;) Using `as.character()` on quosures is deprecated anyway, and will be an error in a future version of rlang.